# What is the difference between currentEra and activeEra

Tags: staking, era

When I look for the `exposures.others.length`, it is not the same as the explorer show. The `exposures.others.length` is 302 but the explorer shows 342. Why? Should I use the `currentEra` or `activeEra`?

```js
const activeEra = (await api.query.staking.activeEra()).unwrap();
const exposures = await api.query.staking.erasStakers.at(blockHash,activeEra.index, address);
```

or

```js
const lastEra = (await api.query.staking.currentEra()).unwrap();
const exposures = await api.query.staking.erasStakers.at(blockHash,lastEra, address);
```

Answer (score 4):

`ActiveEra` is the era that we are on.

`CurrentEra` is the era that staking is on.

For example, if the election failed. `ActiveEra` will still be increased, but the `CurrentEra` not. And one day you found they are not equal, which means your chain's election stalled. `ActiveEra - CurrentEra` eras is the stalled time.

---

> https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/session/src/lib.rs
> https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/staking/src/pallet/impls.rs

Here are the processes of how these two storage changes:

```
start_session -> start_era -> increase ActiveEra
new_session -> try_trigger_new_era -> trigger_new_era -> increase CurrentEra
```

`start_session` and `new_session` will be called [at the same time](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/241b0d0455453499763d0db0b4ea4188012b372f/frame/session/src/lib.rs#L661-L664). So, we should focus on the `start_era` and `try_trigger_new_era`.

`ActiveEra` will be increased immediately when [`start_era`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/241b0d0455453499763d0db0b4ea4188012b372f/frame/staking/src/pallet/impls.rs#L356-L364).

But if the `elect` failed [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/241b0d0455453499763d0db0b4ea4188012b372f/frame/staking/src/pallet/impls.rs#L463), `try_trigger_new_era` will return `None`. The [`trigger_new_era`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/241b0d0455453499763d0db0b4ea4188012b372f/frame/staking/src/pallet/impls.rs#L498) will be skipped. So, the `CurrentEra` won't be updated.

Comment: Which i can shoule choose at  await api.query.staking.erasStakers? ActiveEra  or CurrentEra

Comment: Use `CurrentEra`.
https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/241b0d0455453499763d0db0b4ea4188012b372f/frame/staking/src/pallet/impls.rs#L432-L444

Comment: `erasStakers` should be queried with `currentEra`. 

Also, note that `ActiveEra` is used for reward related logic.

Answer (score 2):

> Should i use currentEra or activeEra?

Probably `activeEra`. Current Era is mostly used to plan upcoming eras and prepare the network for the validator set change according to a new election. The `currentEra` sets up what will become `active`.

There's a little description of how these relate in Sidecar's [staking progress](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-api-sidecar/blob/8906816/src/controllers/pallets/PalletsStakingProgressController.ts#L61L75) endpoint.